# Qt : Strings display incorrectly in rtl layout

Tags: qt, qt4

i'm writing a qt app that should use right to left layout but there is a problem with displaying strings that include space,digits and letters in **qtreewidget** and **qtablewidget**. for example when i write **65 %c** it shows as **c% 65** and of course date times shown as **"22:10:06 2015-01-06"** instead of **"2015-01-06 22:10:06"**

how can i fix this?

screenshot:
[image]

thank you

Comment: Please post relevant parts of the code.

Comment: i use qt designer for entering texts. in both qt designer and app text shown as i mentioned

Comment: if you want i can send you some screenshots

Comment: @SantaXYZ You can add screenshots to the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91719

Comment: @Simon Warta i dont have enough reputation for posting images but this is the link of screenshot http://i58.tinypic.com/vfuw44.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use rtl layout all children assume that your writing language is also rtl.
Digits are universal so they are treated depending on this setting.
When you use ltr characters (Latin for example) this gives this "funny" side effect (it is even more funny when you edit this text, cursor will jump to different position when moved by arrows).

One way to fix it is add Unicode [Left-to-right mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) characters where it is needed.

IMO it would be better do not use this feature (rtl layout) if your language is ltr. Let locale setting do this magic.

Can you explain how and why did you used "rtl layout"? What did you tried to achieve that you have decided ti change text direction?

Comment: my application should be translated in eight languages and 3 of these languages are rtl. for this reason i design my ui in rtl layout in qt designer and when user changes the language, layout direction in application would be changed to language's direction (rtl or ltr).

Comment: than you have to work on localization. Date and time should be converted to string based on current locale. If you are mixing languages you should add "Left-to-right mark" in respective localization. Read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/internationalization.html